# Static files not loaded when deploy a django web page in vercel(with whitenoise)

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, whitenoise

[when the project is deployed shows this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxVBu.png)
here is my settings.py:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'me',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'Matheus.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'Matheus.wsgi.application'

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "staticfiles" / "static"

if DEBUG:
    STATICFILES_DIRS=['staticfiles']
    STATIC_ROOT = None
else:
    STATICFILES_DIRS=[]
    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

# Whitenoise Storage Class  - Apply compression but don’t want the caching behaviour
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'
```

here is my vercel.json:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
      {
          "src": "Matheus/wsgi.py",
          "use": "@vercel/python",
          "config": {
              "maxLambdaSize": "15mb",
              "runtime": "python3.12"
          }
      },
      {
          "src": "build.sh",
          "use":"@vercel/static-build",
          "config":{
              "distDir": "staticfiles"
          }
      }
  ],
  "routes": [
      {
          "src":"/static/(.*)",
          "dest":"/static/$1"
      },
      {
          "src": "/(.*)",
          "dest": "Matheus/wsgi.py"
      }
  ]
}
```

here is my build.sh:

````
#!/bin/bash

# Update pip
echo "Updating pip..."
python3.12 pip install -U pip

# Install dependencies

echo "Installing project dependencies..."
python3.12 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

# Make migrations
echo "Making migrations..."
python3.12 manage.py makemigrations --noinput
python3.12 manage.py migrate --noinput
#Install whitenoise
echo Installing white noise..."
python3.12 manage.py whitenoise
# Collect staticfiles
echo "Collect static..."
python3.12 manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear

echo "Build process completed!"```

wsgi config :
````

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Matheus.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

# vercel config

app = application # add this line.
```

https://github.com/Matheus-Dimon/me/tree/teste

I want to a config to change that can make the deploy serves the staticfiles.

Comment: `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR, 'templates']` Did you mean `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']` ?

Comment: with 'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'] the server got crashed error 500

Comment: Can you post the actual error message from the server error log?

Comment: welcomescript.js:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
welcomestyle.css:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
/favicon.ico:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
welcomestyle.css:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: Those are 404 errors.  Do you see any errors specifically regarding the 500 response?

Comment: when i try change the "dirs" i found these errors (500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED
ID: gru1:gru1::6brvs-1698626939209-7e35ef19c606 ) in home page and( me-ie61zm9gm-matheus-dimons-projects.vercel.app/:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
/favicon.ico:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()
me-ie61zm9gm-matheus-dimons-projects.vercel.app/:1 
        
        
       Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ())

Comment: Those messages are pretty generic.  Are there any log messages that say what the actual code error was?  Like an actual python code traceback message?

Comment: no , my code passed the debug in python and can use python manage.py runserver without any problems

Comment: i have 4 branches in github with 4 diferent configurations 2 of then are running but dont  serve static 1 version with whitenoise and 1 without . and 2 versions are the 2 changes in urls sugested in this tipoc wich both got crashed debug True and False

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way when Debug is False...

In urls.py (the main one)

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.static import serve
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls')),
    re_path(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),

    re_path(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
```

For the settings.py... I did this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'



if DEBUG:

  STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

else:

  STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')



MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

If Debug is True, do it this way...
urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls'))
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings.py

```
import os
...
...
...
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [BASE_DIR / 'static/']
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: i try this solution for debug = False but got 500: INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
Code: FUNCTION_INVOCATION_FAILED
ID: gru1:gru1::x8mbl-1698532227395-929219c2ca31

Comment: both codes debug True and False got crash error 500 in deploy i ve created a new branch for each in gith hub

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check on vercel if you realy have folder `staticfiles/static` or `static`. I had not any despite of having `python manage.py collectstatic` in `buildfiles.sh` and `distDir` similary to yours in `vercel.json`. Static files of course have not worked (with `DEBUG = False`). So, firstly, I decided to change `vercel.json` in line 7 and make `ditDir: 'static'` like below:

```
{
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "build_files.sh",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": {
        "distDir": "static"
      }
    },
    {
      "src": "/czarny_kot/wsgi.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb" }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "czarny_kot/wsgi.py"
    }

  ]
}
```

Secondly, i've deleted line with collectstatic from `buildfiles.sh`. After I set lines in `settings.py` like bellow:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    # ...
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'static'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', HomeViews.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('tinymce/',include('tinymce.urls')),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Finally I run `python manage.py collectstatic` locally and after committed and pushed all stuff to github. As u can see on this page: [czornykot.pl](https://czornykot.pl) statics works - there is no lack of any static image, css, or js. Hope it's going to work on your page :)

edit: `BASE_DIR / ...` works if u have this in `settings.py`:

```
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

I'm using Whitnoise.

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

Comment: u are using whitenoise?

Comment: yes, i am using whitenoise

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution with these configs:
in vercel.json i change this :

```
"src": "build_files.sh",
  "use": "@vercel/static",
  "config": {
    "distDir": "staticfiles_build"
```

in settings.py this config:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = os.path.join('me' , 'static'),
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

and url.py of app put this :

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```